How to prove that TWO-COLORED-HAMILTONIAN-CYCLE is NP-complete?
Consider the following problems:
TCHC :=
{
⟨G, c⟩ | G(V, E) is a directed graph with an even number of vertices along with
an edge coloring c and G has a directed Hamiltonian cycle with no
two consecutive edges of the same color
}.
DHC :=
{
⟨G'⟩ | G'(V', E') is a directed graph that has a directed Hamiltonian cycle
}.
Assume that DHC is NP-complete.
I'm trying to reduce DHC to TCHC, but I'm having trouble with the case when DHC is an odd Hamiltonian cycle. I tried adding an extra vertex, but I failed to come up with such an arrangement of edges that all True/False answers from DHC would map to TCHC. I'd highly appreciate any pointers or solutions.

Each vertex in the colored graph has a set of incoming red, outgoing red, incoming blue, and outgoing blue edges.
In the colored graph, decompose each vertex into five like below to create a colorless graph:

Here 1,2,3,4,5 represent the decomposed vertix.  (8,3) represents all the incoming blue edges, and if there are more then add more (like 8a, 8b, 8c...).  Or if there is no incoming blue edge then delete 8.
There is only 1 path from 6 to 9 that covers all of 1,2,3,4,5.
If you create a 6 to 7 path, then it is impossible to make a 8 to 9 path that covers the remaining vertices.
And the other color is symmetric.
This should be enough to show TCHC is polytime solvable with DHC.
A similar much simpler decomposition can be used to go the other direction.
